# How can I make my array choose different choices each time it runs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

Right now, I have an array with three options. I have a function set up so it chooses one option each time, but sometimes it repeats outputs. How can I code it so the same color does no repeat twice in a row?

```
<!DOCTYPEhtml>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Tester</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var colors = ['#ce0e0e', '#079b0c', '#3e3fd6'];

        function changeColor(){
            var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
            while (myDiv.style.backgroundColor == randomColor)
                randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

            myDiv.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .divClass {
            width:300px;
            height:300px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-radius:1000px;
            background-color:transparent;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class=divClass id="myDiv" style="border:6px solid black;">
    </div>

    <input id=button type=button value="chagne color" onclick='changeColor()'>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use the unique = true but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: You could implement an array that keeps the values you already had. Then you have to compare if the array contains your current value. If so, get another value. If not, choose the value...

Comment: "Is there a way to make it not repeat?"  Yes there is.  Can you please edit the question to inform what, if anything, you tried.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPEhtml>` is invalid! Missing a space. Should be `<!DOCTYPE html>` or `<!doctype html>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var colors = ['#ce0e0e', '#079b0c', '#3e3fd6'];
        var old;

        function changeColor(){

            var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
            if(old){

                if(old !== randomColor){


                    myDiv.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
                    old = randomColor;
                } else {
                    setTimeout(changeColor,300);
                }
            } else {
                myDiv.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
                old = randomColor;



            }
        }
    </script>
```

They won't repeat now.
Old keeps the value of the first/previous click. If you get same value you relaunch function until it changes.

50+ clicks and never same color twice

Comment: That's true, but it's possible that the same 2 colors flip flop several times before the third color comes into play.

Comment: How come? I swap value and I only want not to fall on previous color

Comment: You have 3 colors. You memorize only the last one. So, if the Math.random() plays a joke on you it's possible that you only switch between `#ce0e0e` and `#079b0c` for a long time, for example.

Comment: Thank you Dice, I'm going to use this one because that fits best long run!

Comment: You know it's only maths Lynx. But I agree your solution is cool, but I'd modify it

Answer (score 1):

```
var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];    
function changeColor(){ 
        var newColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        if(newColor==color){
          changeColor();
        } else {
          color = newColor;
          myDiv.style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
    }
```

you should use a recursive function

Comment: When I ran this, I found it still repeated colors. I didn't think of using an if else statement so I'll play around with it! Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I had not put all the code. Read it now, this is what I wanted to say.